Posición de la leyendo en gráfico en RStudio
tengo este código
'''
plot(frecuencias, main = 'Tiempo de vuelo',
     xlab = 'Tiempo', ylab = 'Frecuencia')
abline(v=mean(vuelos$tiempo_vuelo), col = 'red')
abline(v=median(vuelos$tiempo_vuelo), col = 'blue')
legend('topright',cex = 0.8,
       c('Media','Mediana'),
       col = c('red','blue'))

'''
El gráfico que consigo es el siguiente:

La pregunta es: ¿alguien por acá podría decirme por qué la leyenda se ve así?
